# Model.fit_generator is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: tensorflow, keras

As i use these codes

```
r = model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=50,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set)
)
```

i get this error, what is problem and what is solution ?

```
Model.fit_generator is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit here they are saying model.fit_generator is deprecated from long time ago just use ````Model.fit````

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace model.fit_generator with model.fit

Comment: InvalidArgumentError:  var and grad do not have the same shape[1] [3]